# E: Unable to locate package php5-apcu

Tags: ubuntu, php, php.ini, alternative-php-cache, apc

trying to install APCu on Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install php5-apcu
```

Getting an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php5-apcu
```

Following someone's suggestion I added:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
```

To my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

All to no avail. Please help.

P.S. Updating package list for apt-get did not help either.

Comment: What version of ubuntu?

Comment: Also, you added an debian repo to an ubuntu server. That's not a good idea.